# SDL Textures and CPU\Memory issues

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I developed a game with SDL2.00 and c++. I seemed to be having memory and CPU issues. CPU usage goes up to 40% and memory usage goes up by 5mg a second.

So I think the reason is the way Im handling Textures\Sprites.

My question is should I create a different/new sprite/texture for every instance ?

For example, I have a class called Enemy which contains all the variable and methods related to enemy monsters such as HP, damage, location , image(Texture) etc. This class contains its own texture to be rendered onto the renderer.

Is this the right way? Or should  I create a Sprite/Texture for all the images before hand and render them as needed?

and I'm wondering if this will render two different images onto the renderer:

```
RenderCopy(renderer, image);
image->SetPosition(X,Y);
RenderCopy(renderer,image);
```

or is it going to move the sprite to the new position?

I think my issues are caused my overloading the renderer and/or having too many textures being loaded.

Let me know what you think .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is should I create a different/new sprite/texture for
>   every instance ?

No, not unless every instance of the sprite uses different textures, otherwise you should reuse them, ie only load them once and store a pointer to the texture the sprite uses.

> and I'm wondering if this will render two different images onto the
>   renderer:
>
> ```
> RenderCopy(renderer, image); 
> image->SetPosition(X,Y);
> RenderCopy(renderer,image);
> ```
>
> or is it going to move the sprite to the new position?

This will copy the image twice. First at the old position and then at the new. What you will get is a trailing image. You should probably either clear the previous position or render the background at that position (or whatever should be there).

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This explains why my memory keeps getting screwed. I use a different sprite for every different instance of everything haha. Like projectiles, new enemy monsters. so things getting piled up. I will fix it now. And it seems like as the memory use increases CPU does too. But that can also be related to how SDL handles events. Ive seen other people complain about cpu usage caused by SDL event handling too.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is not a scene graph. It's a drawing API. So everytime you're allocating a new texture you're creating a new data object that consumes memory. You should reuse and share resources where possible.